# Assistance with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, grid-layout

I need some assistance with an assignment that deals with Jframes. The assignment says "For questions 27 to 31, consider the following class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class A extends JFrame
(
   private Container c;
   private JButton b;
   private JTextField tf;
)
```

Now for the questions:
29.Inside the constructor, this code instantiates the text field tf; after instantiation, the text field should be empty but have space for 10 characters.

30.Inside the constructor, and assuming that c has been assigned the content pane. this code sets the layout manager of the content pane to a 2-by-1 grid layout manager.

This is what I have for question 29:

```
tf = new JTextField(10);
```

I am not sure how to do quesion 30 though. Any tips would be wonderful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of GridLayout and assign it to the container.

```
final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2,1);
c.setLayout(layout);
```